# Swift / User privacy location always Usage

Tags: swift, location, mapkit, cllocationmanager

Hey guys I need the permission of the user to have always his location. I have implemented these three properties in the info.plist:

[image]

And this is my Code on the ViewController in the viewDidLoad Function:

```
locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
```

But it just shows me this:

[image]

What can I do to get the always allow permission like these?

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I might be wrong but it could be that Apple just removed the option for a third-party app to have constant access to location.

Comment: Did you check that [solution](https://medium.com/swlh/location-permission-in-ios-13-f9e10917c05e) ?